# On the compactness in Sion's minimax theorem

Tags: general-topology, optimization

In wikipedia and a lot of research papers, Sion's minimax theorem is quoted as follows:

> Let $X$ be a compact convex subset of a linear topological space and $Y$ a convex
>   subset of a linear topological space. Let $f$ be a real-valued function on $X \times Y$
>   such that 1. $f(x, \cdot)$ is
>    upper semicontinuous and quasi-concave on $Y$ for each $x \in X$.
>   2. $f( \cdot, y)$is lower semicontinuous and quasi-convex on $X$ for each $y \in Y$. Then: $$\inf_{x \in X}\sup_{y \in Y}f(x,y) = \sup_{y \in Y}\inf_{x \in X}f(x,y)$$

Such quotations are referring to 3.3 Corollary of 3.4 Theorem in the original article:

> Sion, Maurice. "On general minimax theorems." Pacific J. Math 8.1 (1958): 171-176,

which is available in the internet. The original version is different than the one stated above. In Sion's work, either X or Y can be compact. He does not differentiate.

I wonder whether there is a reason why the above version is more widely quoted in the literature than Sion's original. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you let

$$ g(y,x) = - f(x,y) $$

then $g$ is a function on $Y\times X$ that is usc and quasi-concave on the second variable, and lsc and quasi-convex on the first variable. So the $Y$ compact version follows immediately from the $X$ compact version.

In other words, if you are in a situation to apply Sion's theorem, you can always rename your variables in a way that you can apply the "common version" you quoted. The choice that $X$ is the one written as the compact one probably has to do with the fact that in Sion's original proof that's the version that he showed, leaving the simple modification for the version with $Y$ being compact to the reader.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. It was enlightening. For rigor, I would like to point out that $g(y,x)$ above is still compact on $x$ so we cannot directly apply the above theorem. On the other hand, mutlipying both sides of the equality, we get

Comment: $$- \inf_{x \in X}\sup_{y \in Y}f(x,y) = - \sup_{y \in Y}\inf_{x \in X}f(x,y)$$ and equivalently $$\sup_{x \in X}\inf_{y \in Y} - f(x,y) = \inf_{y \in Y}\sup_{x \in X} - f(x,y)$$. Now calling $g(x,y)=-f(x,y)$, we get the version with compactness on $X$, which is the domain of maximization.

Comment: On the other hand, in Sion's original proof, the domain of maximization is assumed to be compact (unlike wikipedia and other resources) and the counterpart is left to the reader.